# Erubis not working when executed from PHP

Tags: php, ruby, erubis

I'm calling a Ruby script from PHP with `system('ruby show.rb filename')`.

The show.rb looks like this:

```
require 'erubis'
f = ARGV[0]
puts f
input = File.read(f)
eruby = Erubis::Eruby.new(input)
puts eruby.result(binding())
```

When executing the command `ruby show.rb filename` in the console everything is printed out, but when calling it from PHP it's only printing the filename, but the template is not rendered. To see errors I piped stderr -> stdout in the PHP call and I got this

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/converter.rb:132:in 'scan': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/converter.rb:132:in 'convert_input' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/converter.rb:36:in 'convert' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/engine.rb:30:in 'initialize' from show.rb:5:in 'new' from show.rb:5:in temp/Newsletter.rb'`

I'm new to Ruby. Are there maybe any option parameters to fix this? What is PHP doing differently there, that the error can occur?

Comment: How do you call it form php?

Comment: As mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: First thing: `'ruby show.rb filename'` not the same as `ruby script.rb filename`. Second check your php file code page to be UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the error in the question with the name. It’s show.rb

Comment: What about code page?

Comment: Every file involved in the process is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when opening a erubis template file inside show.rb called by PHP it must be opened as a binary file. So I only had to change show.rb to:

```
require 'erubis'
f = ARGV[0]
handle = File.open(f, "rb") # "rb" fixed the issue.
input = handle.read()
handle.close()
eruby = Erubis::Eruby.new(input)
puts eruby.result(binding())
```